# Could not compile js files in angular 11

Tags: angular, typescript

We have an angular 11 application. And we try to import a file with .js extension (I cannot use .ts as the main file of the library is in index.js)

For testing purpose

**test.js**

```
const ALL_TOOLS = new Set([
  'alpha',
  'beta',
  'gamma'
]);


const SelectorPack = (anno, config) => {

  // Add configured tools, or all
  const useTools = config?.tools ? 
    new Set(config.tools.map(t => t.toLowerCase())) : ALL_TOOLS;

  console.log(useTools)

}

export default SelectorPack;
```

**mycomponent.component.ts**

```
 import * as SelectorPack from './test'

 constructor() {  
 console.log(SelectorPack)
 }
```

I am getting this error
[image]

How can we compile a js code with angular application

**tsconfig.json**

```
/* To learn more about this file see: https://angular.io/config/tsconfig. */
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you try a different import style such as `import SelectorPack from './test';` ?

Comment: I get the same error

Comment: The compiler seems to struggle on the chaining operator (`?.`) which is a quite recent feature (ES2020). Can you check the value of `compilerOptions.module` in `tsconfig.json` ? (`es2020` should be fine)

Comment: Try to remove default in the export

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle The tsconfig.json is updated for your reference. In short, yes it is es2020